# Vue app with multiple entry files in webpack config [duplicate contents]

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm making Vue app with 2 pages(entry files) using 1 webpack setting. The problem is the generated entry files have the same contents in it. **file1** has the content of **file2** and vice versa.

I have this entry points:

```
 entry: {
    'page1': ['./src/pages/page1/main'],
    'page2': ['./src/pages/page2/main'],
    'vendor': [
       // Node module libraries

     ]
 },
 output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[name].[id].js',
  path: config.dev.assetsRoot
}
```

I'm using .vue files so I need voe-loader.
Below is the vue-loader options:

```
loaders: {
    'ts': 'ts-loader!tslint-loader', // Let ts-loader and tslint validate .vue script
    'i18n': '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader', // i18n loader for Message properties
    /**
     * SCSS loader for .vue scss files and extract the text to usr-styles.css
     */
    'scss': ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: false                        
                }
            }, 
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: false                        
                }
            }
        ]
    }),
    /**
     * CSS loader for .vue css files and extract the text to usr-styles.css
     */
    'css': ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: false                        
                }
            }, 
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: false                        
                }
            }
        ]
    })
},
extractCSS: true,
esModule: true,
cssSourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
cacheBusting: config.dev.cacheBusting,
transformToRequire: {
    video: ['src', 'poster'],
    source: 'src',
    img: 'src',
    image: 'xlink:href'
}
```

So here is my main.ts

```
import App from './App.vue';

// Creation of Vue instance
const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   i18n,
   store,
   render: h => h(App)
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <el-container>
          page1
  </el-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Header from 'Header/Header.vue';
import Baselayout from 'page1/Baselayout.vue';

@Component({
  components: {
      'header-view': Header,
      'baselayout-view': Baselayout
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue { }
</script>
```

Some of the plugin versions:

```
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0",
"ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.6.2",
...
```

So basically page1 has different imports of components as well as page2.
But they are common with utility, contants and vendor.

I just don't understand why the generated files for page1 and page2 have the same content inside?
Is it not possible to have multiple entry file when developing Vue application?

I need help for this or the other way is to provide another webpack setting for another page which is not ideal for me.

Comment: I have found the cause, it's because of loadLanguageAsync https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/lazy-loading.html, 
this line "return import(`../../${screenId}/message_properties/${params.lang}`).then( ... )" i'll investigate further.

Comment: Can you please post what you found? Thanks.

Comment: @F.Gran when using lazy load specially switching of screens duplicate contents will occur in my case.